# Как правильно использовать ContentProvider (в части архитектуры приложения)?

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Вопрос простой, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно применять `ContentProvider` для нескольких таблиц БД? Либо нужно делать на каждую таблицу свой `ContentProvider`?

Читал разные мнения, в основном `ContentProvider` используют в качестве некой `ORM` над БД без выхода данных наружу, хотя суть `ContentProvider` в организации внешнего доступа к данным приложения. Поэтому хочу сразу разобраться в вопросе, чтоб потом переделывать меньшее количество раз.
У меня есть рабочий `ContentProvider` для одной таблицы, возникла необходимость воткнуть еще несколько таблиц, и я не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать. Если все пихать в один `ContentProvider`, то он распухнет сильно, значит нужно несколько делать, но непонятно, насколько это правильное решение...

В общем, подскажите варианты с обоснованием плюсов/минусов, как народ делает это.

Comment: речь идёт о БД вашего приложения? На личном опыте скажу, что лучше не пользуйтесь контент провайдерами. используйте только в случае предоставления доступа к данным приложения из вне. для внутренней работы есть огромное количество удобных ORM. самая модная сейчас это Room

Comment: Почему не надо использовать? Поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста.

Comment: контент провайдер для внутреннего использования не даст ничего, кроме дополнительного геморроя по созданию этого провайдера. Есть еще вариант, что его требует CursorLoader, но проще переопределить сам CursorLoader, чтобы работал напрямую с курсором, чем писать для него контент провайдер. Его не надо использовать, потому что затраты на его создание не принесут никаких улучшений, он используется только для внешнего доступа к вашей бд (из других приложений) - если такого доступа нет, то он излишен

Comment: Вы правы, я понимаю, что ContentProvider это лишнее звено в цепочке, но как переопределить CursorLoader, ткните, пожалуйста, в ссылку на материал, я еще не очень разбираюсь в этом.